# Make volume bold in custom bibliography style .bst

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, formatting, lyx, custom-bib

Since I could not find the style that met my teacher's requirements for the bibliography I have to do, I created my own `bst` with `latex makebst` on my mac. I had chosen to make the volume `bold` but it does not appear in boldface on my document (I am using LyX). I was wondering if there is a way to make it appear in bold by modifying the `bst` file

This is what I have in the volume section

```
FUNCTION {format.bvolume}
{ volume empty$
    { "" }
    { bbl.volume volume tie.or.space.prefix
      "volume" bibinfo.check * *
      series "series" bibinfo.check
      duplicate$ empty$ 'pop$
        { emphasize ", " * swap$ * }
      if$
      "volume and number" number either.or.check
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.number.series}
{ volume empty$
    { number empty$
        { series field.or.null }
        { series empty$
            { number "number" bibinfo.check }
            { output.state mid.sentence =
                { bbl.number }
                { bbl.number capitalize }
              if$
              number tie.or.space.prefix "number" bibinfo.check * *
              bbl.in space.word *
              series "series" bibinfo.check *
            }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
    { "" }
  if$
}
```

Can someone help me solve this problem ? I tried to add `{\bf }` around `* swap$ *` but it does not seem to be working.

Comment: Hello and welcome :)  You can use backticks `\`` to mark inline code fragments as I did in my edit.

Comment: Which "volume" concept do you refer to: That for a *book* (in a multivolume series, such as an encyclopedia), or that for a journal's *volume*? The BibTeX functions you display, `format.bvolume` and `format.number.series`, pertain to the former concept of "volume". If you're interested in the journal-related volume concept, you should be examining the function `format.vol.num.pages`.

Comment: I want to make the Journal volume in bold

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The language of BibTeX style is based on reverse Polish notation. This means that it puts strings on a stack and the functions operates on the last element(s) in the stack. Thus to make the current element of the stack bold, one can create the following function

```
FUNCTION {makebold}{
  "\textbf{" swap$ * "}" * }
}
```

This function assumes  that there is an element on the stack, then it adds the string `\textbf{` to the stack, thus after this step the stack is `"element" "\textbf{"`. The instruction `swap$` inverts the order  of the last two elements in the stack. `*` replaces the last two elements with their concatenation. Thus after the first `*` the last element of  the stack is `"\textbf{element"`.  Then we append "}" to the stack and finally we concatenate it with the previous element.  Thus we obtain `"\textbf{element}"`.

After defining the function you can replace `emphasize` with `makebold` (or see the comment by Mico about the other relevant functions)

Comment: Thank you very much. I found out there was a `bolden` function in the ".bst" file at the top. I wrote `bolden` before `swap$` instead of emphasize and I wrote  `bolden` just before `volume` in `format.vol.num.pages`. I don't know for sure which one is the right solution but it worked.