# LyX: author-year not compatible with natbib package with custom bst

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I have a problem with LyX and citation. I would like to use the option Natbib : Author-Year to display the citation like "(Gebel *et al*., 2009)" but I keep getting the error `author-year not compatible with natbib package`. I am using a custom ".bst" file. It works fine if I just want to show numbers as "[1]"

Can anyone help me solve this problem ? Would it work better with TeXmaker ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that author-year in `natbib` requires to have `bibitem`s with the following form:

```
\bibitem[Short(year)Long]{citekey} ...
```

Where `Short` is the short list of authors (e.g., Gebel et al in your case) and `Long` is the full list of authors.  So the solution is to change the `.bst`. You can try to see if the `bst` file you use has a function  `output.bibitem`, check that it is called  in `FUNCTION{book}`, `FUNCTION{article}` and for the other BibTeX entry types,  and then replace the `output.bibitem` function with:

```
FUNCTION {output.bibitem}
{ newline$
  "\bibitem[{" write$
  label write$
  ")" make.full.names duplicate$ short.list =
     { pop$ }
     { * }
   if$
  "}]{" * write$
  cite$ write$
  "}" write$
  newline$
  ""
  before.all 'output.state :=
}
```

Otherwise, you since in a previous question  [Make volume bold in custom bibliography style .bst](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82499/16895) you wrote you created your own `bst` using `custom-bib`. You can create it again specifying the right options for `natbib` and `author-year`.

Comment: I found the bibitem function and edited it but now I have a new error "Paragraph ended before Ibibitem was complete."

Comment: @esmitex Not knowing what the rest of the `bst` file is a bit hard.  Can you give an example of a `\bibitem` produced by BibTeX? (look in the `.bbl` file)

Comment: I created a new bst file using "author-year" but now I have to do it again, I have a colon instead of a comma after the volume. I don't know how to edit that in the bst file. This is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 2):

For who might still be interested..
I had the same problem as esmitex with Guido's answer. I had to modify it, so I ended up with the following solution:

Replace `FUNCTION {output.bibitem}` with

```
    FUNCTION {output.bibitem}
    { newline$
      "\bibitem[{" write$ make.short.names "}(" * year empty$ {skip$} { year * } if$ "){" * make.full.names * "}]{" * write$
     cite$ write$
     "}" write$
     newline$
     ""
     before.all 'output.state :=
}
```

I also had to precede the above code with the following additional functions:

```
    FUNCTION {format.full.names}
{'s :=
 "" 't :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr
      "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
      't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        {
          namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            {
              s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ duplicate$ "others" =
                { 't := }
                { pop$ }
              if$
              t "others" =
                {
                  " " * bbl.etal emphasize *
                }
                {
                  "\&"
                  space.word * t *
                }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}

FUNCTION {format.short.names}
{'s := 
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
    numnames #1 >  
    { s #1 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ " " * bbl.etal emphasize * } 
    { numnames #1 =  { s #1 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ } { "NN" } if$ }
    if$
 }

FUNCTION {author.editor.key.full}
{ author empty$
    { editor empty$
        { key empty$
            { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
            'key
          if$
        }
        { editor format.full.names }
      if$
    }
    { author format.full.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {author.editor.key.short}
{ author empty$
    { editor empty$
        { key empty$
            { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
            'key
          if$
        }
        { editor format.short.names }
      if$
    }
    { author format.short.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {author.key.full}
{ author empty$
    { key empty$
         { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
          'key
      if$
    }
    { author format.full.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {author.key.short}
{ author empty$
    { key empty$
         { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
          'key
      if$
    }
    { author format.short.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {editor.key.full}
{ editor empty$
    { key empty$
         { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
          'key
      if$
    }
    { editor format.full.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {editor.key.short}
{ editor empty$
    { key empty$
         { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
          'key
      if$
    }
    { editor format.short.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {make.full.names}
{ type$ "book" =
  type$ "inbook" =
  or
    'author.editor.key.full
    { type$ "proceedings" =
        'editor.key.full
        'author.key.full
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {make.short.names}
{ type$ "book" =
  type$ "inbook" =
  or
    'author.editor.key.short
    { type$ "proceedings" =
        'editor.key.short
        'author.key.short
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

If you already have any of these functions defined, you might want to keep them or replace them.
The function `make.short.names` defines the author list to be displayed inline in text when using \citeauthor or \citet. This version shows John *et al.* [11] or just John [11] in case of a single author.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add " extra.label *" to "year *" in FUNCTION {output.bibitem} if you use the author-year mode and get

```
FUNCTION {output.bibitem}
{ newline$
  "\bibitem[{" write$ make.short.names "}(" * year empty$ {skip$} { year * extra.label * } if$ "){" * make.full.names * "}]{" * write$
 cite$ write$
 "}" write$
 newline$
 ""
 before.all 'output.state :=
}
```

in case that the citations is the same author and the same year
e.g. Titman et al. (2010a,b). Otherwise, it look like Titman et al. (2010,?)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).