# How to add author-year support to a .bst file?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing, natbib, custom-bib

I'm currently trying to format my references according to the [DeGruyter Open Computer Science guidelines](https://www.degruyter.com/view/supplement/s22991093_Instruction_for_Authors.pdf), and I've made a custom .bst file for this.

However, in my paper, I use natbib's `citet` a bunch, and while I need to print the citations themselves numerically, I rely heavily on `citet`'s ability to retrieve the author name from the citation.

However, I'm currently getting `(author?)` printed any time I call `citet`.

What do I need to add to my .bst file to allow `citet` to print the author names?

Comment: The specifics of a useful implementation will depend on the style, so I can't give a proper answer without having seen the full `.bst` file. But my answer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/439309/35864 shows roughly what you need to do. You need to inject author-date information into the optional argument of `\bibitem`. (For background see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/459161/35864 as linked in your other question.) See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82569/35864, but as I say the exact modifications needed are style-dependent.

Comment: Any news here? Could you solve your problem? If you are still interested in an answer, it would really help if you could show us your entire `.bst` file and a short example document.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, the easiest thing was to make a new .bst file with `makebst`, that replicated the style of the original `.bst`, but had author-year support enabled.

Basically, my understanding is that how author-year support is implemented is `bst`-specific, so there's no generic way to add it to an existing package.