# Alternatives to citet when bst doesn't support authoryear

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing, natbib

I've got an article where the publisher is requiring I use a specific citation format. The bibtex style doesn't support author year, but throughout my document, I've been using `\citet` for textual references to the author's names.

I'm wondering, is there an alternative to citet that will automatically print the author's name and the reference number, but that doesn't require specific support from the bst style?

Comment: Basically no, I have written about the background and why in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/459161/35864. There is the package [`usebib`](https://ctan.org/pkg/usebib) that could alternatively be used to extract data from the `.bib` file in TeX, but it doesn't do name fields, because they require complicated parsing. Your best bet is to modify the `.bst` file to support the author-year format.

Comment: Does the publisher provide a bst file that supports the required "look" of citation call-outs? A separate question: Is something stopping you from doing a global rename of `\citet` to `\cite`?

Comment: @Mico I've found a .bst someone else has made that mostly matches the publisher's format (DeGruyter), I've got [a related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/460046/how-to-add-author-year-support-to-a-bst-file) on how to modify it. If I renamed `\citet` to `cite` I would have a bunch of sentences that were missing author names, which would be odd.

Comment: In some styles you can use `\newcite`