# Natbib returns (Author?) when using citep and the nature.sty bib style

Tags: natbib

Is there any way for natbib to recognise I want to cite my references as

> Name [ 1 ]

? At present I get an error which reads "bibliography style not compatible with author year citations".

```
NAT@force@numbers{}\NAT@force@numbers
```

[image]

Comment: When you say nature.sty bib style do you refer to `nature.bst` as found on http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/academic/biology/ecology+evolution/tex/nature.bst? This style does not appear to be compatible with `natbib`. Would it be possible to use a different style?

Comment: That's the one, how would I incorporate it?

Comment: Is there any reason why you absolutely want to stick to this (as far as I can tell) unofficial and outdated `.bst` file? It is possible to make existing `.bst` files "`natbib`-ready", but it can be painful, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/439309/35864 has an example (I'll check the linked post if there is one with a better explanation). If you are not married to the idea of having to use `nature.bst` I'd recommend you just take a different style like `unsrtnat`.

Comment: Another example is https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82569/35864. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/459161/35864 has some background you may or may not find illuminating.

Comment: I have to write a dissertation and that's the template they gave me. I might just have to use makebst

Comment: Question is: How much do they really want you to use the template as is? How strict are they in general about formatting requirements and bibliography formatting requirements specifically. Many dissertation templates I have seen so far are not really state of the art and accrue more and more unused and outdated code until they just cease to function properly one day. A `.bst` file from more than 25 years ago that doesn't support URLs or DOIs does not make me think we're talking about a very modern or well-maintained template here.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree. My university is very stuck in its ways