# Natbib not working when using naturemag

Tags: natbib

So I'm trying to get `\citet{}` to work using naturemag.bst and I can't get the Author's name to print.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{naturemag}

\begin{document}

\citet{krumholz2011star}

\bibliography{refs}

\end{document}
```

bib file:

```
@COMMENT intro
@inproceedings{krumholz2011star,
    title={Star formation in molecular clouds},
    author={Krumholz, Mark R},
    booktitle={AIP Conference Proceedings},
    volume={1386},
    number={1},
    pages={9--57},
    year={2011},
    organization={AIP}
}
@article{randall1999large,
    title={Large mass hierarchy from a small extra dimension},
    author={Randall, Lisa and Sundrum, Raman},
    journal={Physical review letters},
    volume={83},
    number={17},
    pages={3370},
    year={1999},
    publisher={APS}
}
```

The output I get:

[image]

Comment: See the bibtex log: ``Package natbib Warning: Author undefined for citation`krumholz2011star' 
(natbib)                on page 1 on input line 7.``

Comment: The problem is, all the authors are defined in that field.

Comment: The issue is that you are trying to do author extraction (`\citet`) but naturemag.bst does not support that, only `\cite`. If you look in the `.bbl` file, then `naturemag` is used we get say `\bibitem{einstein}`, but with a style fully compatible with all of `natbib`, say, `plainnat` we get `\bibitem[Einstein(1905{\natexlab{a}})]{einstein}` note the data in `[]`'s, that is the author data that `\citet` is looking for. Conclusing `naturemag` does not support anything other than just numbers. (which is what nature uses everywhere, isn't it)

Comment: Pretty much the same issue as https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/512475/35864: `naturemag` is not compatible with `natbib`'s extended author-year features because it doesn't provide the necessary data.