# Add custom field to bibtex entry, and print it

Tags: bibtex, custom-bib

I want to add a volume field to `@manual`. This is the `@manual` function generated by `makebst`

```
FUNCTION {manual}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors output
  author format.key output
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  new.sentence
  organization "organization" bibinfo.check output
  address "address" bibinfo.check output
  format.edition output
  format.note output
  fin.entry
  write.url
}
```

It should print

> author (year). *title* vol. volume ...

if the `volume`filed is given. Otherwise, i want it as it is.

Like

> Intel Corporation (2015 June), *Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual* vol. 1. Intel Corporation, 2200 Mission College Blvd. Santa Clara, CA
>   95054-1549 USA.

Here is the bib item:

```
@manual
    {
    intelman
    ,author={{Intel Corporation}}
    ,title={Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual}
    ,year={2015}
    ,month={June}
    ,language={English}
    ,organization={Intel Corporation}
    ,address={2200 Mission College Blvd. Santa Clara, CA 95054-1549 USA}
    ,volume={1}
    }
```

I am not really comfortable with with RPN, but this should be almost like "Hello, World".

BTW, is there any of

- a system that uses raw XSLT as formatter? I am not a fan of XML, but XSLT is at least very well documented so with that, I should get everything like I want.
- a screen-readable tutorial on "the beast", that is a webpage and not a PDF.

So what I want to do written in C

The bst file is here: https://gist.github.com/milasudril/d5fb8bf376937caaa450

## Addendum

There is another problem with that style:

For `@misc`, I want `howpublished` before the `url`. Given

```
@misc
    {
    wavefront
    ,url={http://www.fileformat.info/format/wavefrontobj/egff.htm}
    ,howpublished={FileFormat.Info}
    ,title={Wavefront OBJ: Summary from the Encyclopedia of Graphics File Formats}
    ,note={2015-07-16}
    ,author={FileFormat.Info}
    ,year={2015}
    }
```

I want

> FileFormat.Info (2015). Wavefront OBJ: Summary from the Encyclopedia of Graphics File Formats. *FileFormat.Info*
>   http://www.fileformat.info/format/wavefrontobj/egff.htm (2015-07-16)

Comment: If you are not that fond of reverse Polish notation, maybe I can interest you in [`biblatex`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex). `biblatex` uses LaTeX-style syntax for its style files (`.bbx` and `.cbx`) and offers an extended seat of features.

Comment: Have you tried adding something along the lines of `volume *` or `volume "volume" bibinfo.check output` in the appropriate place of your `.bst`?

Comment: `volume "volume" bibinfo.check output` is on the right track. I need "vol. " somehow.

Comment: Ahhh, sorry, I missed that. You will have to write you own function then. Maybe you can steal something from the question in [Make volume bold in custom bibliography style .bst](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82499/35864).

Comment: @moewe Could you write an MWE with some comments.

Comment: If you give me a MWE to start from, I will try what I can do. My problem is that I cannot try any code, because I don't know what you have in front of you, so I'm just guessing away.

Comment: @moewe From the questions I have asked here, it appears that the TeX environment is so context sensitive that I need to push the entire report. Too bad Knuth :-(. I can give you pseudocode, or C code or what ever that does exactly what I want, without more.

Comment: The `.bst` file with a very short document citing one or two sources would suufice.

Comment: The bst file is 40k, it is too long for a MVE. If the system is sane a MVE should be less than 20 lines. I gave you the output example.

Comment: I agree that a 1.6K-line `.bst` file can hardly be seen as *minimal*, still it greatly helps to solve the problem `:-)`. Also please only ever ask one question at a time. I have only answered the question in the title, the other about the order in `@misc`s seems to be more problematic and has to do with a very weird `write.url` function....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just your `FUNCTION {manual}` read

```
FUNCTION {manual}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors output
  author format.key output
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  format.bvolume output
  new.sentence
  organization "organization" bibinfo.check output
  address "address" bibinfo.check output
  format.edition output
  format.note output
  fin.entry
  write.url
}
```

Where we added `format.bvolume output` after printing the `title`.

Comment: What is "format.bvolume"?

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi `format.bvolume` is the function that prints the volume (in the non-`@article` case). It is defined in the `.bst` file.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way through XML. If someone wants to port this to bibtex, here is the equivalent in XSLT

https://gist.github.com/milasudril/c61abb7abe44fe2270e5