# change .bst file to get journal name bold

Tags: bibtex, formatting

Based on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82499/make-volume-bold-in-custom-bibliography-style-bst) question, I have a certain problem. In my reference list, I want to make the journal title both emphasized and bold (as opposed to only emphasized, as it currently is).

Following the procedure laid out in the above question, I tried defining my own function, as in

```
FUNCTION {makebold}{
  "\textbf{" swap$ * "}" * }
}
```

and then inserting makebold when calling the journal name.

```
    % format journal, volume, number and pages
    % call with
    %   formatted.pages format.journal.vol.num.pages.check
FUNCTION { format.journal.vol.num.pages.check }
{ "journal" journal warning.if.empty
  duplicate$ empty$
  journal    empty$ and
  volume     empty$ and
  number     empty$ and
    { pop$ "" }
    { "\APACjournalVolNumPages{" journal "" makebold.check connect.check
      "}{" *                     volume  "" connect.check
      "}{" *                     number  "" connect.check
      "}{" *                     swap$   "" connect.check
      "}"  *
    }
  if$
}
```

different from the question I reference, and probably the reason why this is not working, is that the file contains the phrase "emphasize" only where the following function "emphasize.check" is defined, and nowhere else--as you can see above, the journal name is not emphasized at all.

```
    % emphasizes top of stack, call with
    %     "string" emphasize.check
FUNCTION {emphasize.check}
{ "\Bem{" swap$
  "}"     swap$
  enclose.check
}
```

So how can it be that the journal name in my reference list is in italics/emphasized (the .bst file does not contain "\textit" neither, nor anything similar), even though the function "emphasize" is nowhere used?

Do I need to work with another file here?

For completion, the complete .bst file can be downloaded from my dropbox [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ik2em6lp7f78gml/myapacite.bst?dl=0) (142kb).

A MWE that calls the bibliography `mwe.bib` and reproduces the problem is here:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}

\begin{filecontents}{mwe.bib}
% This file was created with JabRef 2.11.1.
% Encoding: UTF8

@Unpublished{Ham2015,
  Title                    = {Narcissism and Financial Reporting Quality},
  Author                   = {Charles Ham and Mark H. Lang and Nicholas Seybert and Sean Wang},
  Note                     = {Available at SSRN: http://ssrn.com/abstract=2581157 or http://dx.doi.org/10.2139/ssrn.2581157},
  Year                     = {2015}
}

@Article{Ham2013,
  Title                    = {Narcissism is a Bad Sign: {CEO} Signature Size, Investment, and Performance},
  Author                   = {Ham, Charles and Seybert, Nicholas and Wang, Sean and Lundblad, Justin Leiby and Sevilir, Merih and Tate, Geoff and Williams, Devin and Zarowin, Paul and Zheng, Yue},
  Journal                  = {UNC Kenan-Flagler Research Paper},
  Year                     = {2013},
  Number                   = {2013-1},
  Type                     = {Journal Article}
}

@Article{Wink1991,
  Title                    = {Two faces of narcissism},
  Author                   = {Wink, Paul},
  Journal                  = {Journal of Personality and Social Psychology},
  Year                     = {1991},
  Number                   = {4},
  Pages                    = {590},
  Volume                   = {61},
  ISSN                     = {1939-1315},
  Type                     = {Journal Article}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{apacite}

\begin{document}
blablabla    
\cite{Ham2013}
\cite{Ham2015}
\cite{Wink1991}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{mwe}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How does `myapacite` differ from `apacite`?

Comment: It effectively doesn't, it was changed in a way to stop it from adding [Journal Article] or [Book Chapter] to every reference.

Comment: so what I mean is: nothing, so I just replaced it in the code above. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could redefine the `\APACjournalVolNumPages` command (this is the formatting command that `apacite.bst` uses to format journal articles; see page 41 of the [current (v6.03) manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/apacite)):

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\APACjournalVolNumPages}[4]{%
  \textbf{\Bem{#1}}%             journal
  \ifx\@empty#2\@empty
  \else
    \unskip, \Bem{#2}%  volume
  \fi
  \ifx\@empty#3\@empty
  \else
    \unskip({#3})%      issue number
  \fi
  \ifx\@empty#4\@empty
  \else
    \unskip, {#4}%      pages
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```

Thanks to [Alan Munn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2693/alan-munn) for catching my missing `\makeatletter`-`\makeatother`. Also, see the second part of [nickie's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/287729/89497) for a more elegant implementation of this approach.

**Edit:** Alternatively, and more in the spirit of your question, you could modify the `.bst` file to achieve the same result:

```
FUNCTION { format.journal.vol.num.pages.check }
{ "journal" journal warning.if.empty
  duplicate$ empty$
  journal    empty$ and
  volume     empty$ and
  number     empty$ and
    { pop$ "" }
    { "\APACjournalVolNumPages{\textbf{" journal "" connect.check
      "}}{" *                     volume  "" connect.check
      "}{" *                     number  "" connect.check
      "}{" *                     swap$   "" connect.check
      "}"  *
    }
  if$
}
```

To answer your second question, the journal name is italicized by default because it is formatted with the `\Bem` command, which is `\let` to be `\emph` in `apacite.sty`.

Result (same for either approach, using your modified `myapacite.bst`):

[image: myapacite with bold journal names]

Full MWE (with first option and unmodified `myapacite.bst`):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}

\begin{filecontents}{mwe.bib}
% This file was created with JabRef 2.11.1.
% Encoding: UTF8

@Unpublished{Ham2015,
  Title                    = {Narcissism and Financial Reporting Quality},
  Author                   = {Charles Ham and Mark H. Lang and Nicholas Seybert and Sean Wang},
  Note                     = {Available at SSRN: http://ssrn.com/abstract=2581157 or http://dx.doi.org/10.2139/ssrn.2581157},
  Year                     = {2015}
}

@Article{Ham2013,
  Title                    = {Narcissism is a Bad Sign: {CEO} Signature Size, Investment, and Performance},
  Author                   = {Ham, Charles and Seybert, Nicholas and Wang, Sean and Lundblad, Justin Leiby and Sevilir, Merih and Tate, Geoff and Williams, Devin and Zarowin, Paul and Zheng, Yue},
  Journal                  = {UNC Kenan-Flagler Research Paper},
  Year                     = {2013},
  Number                   = {2013-1},
  Type                     = {Journal Article}
}

@Article{Wink1991,
  Title                    = {Two faces of narcissism},
  Author                   = {Wink, Paul},
  Journal                  = {Journal of Personality and Social Psychology},
  Year                     = {1991},
  Number                   = {4},
  Pages                    = {590},
  Volume                   = {61},
  ISSN                     = {1939-1315},
  Type                     = {Journal Article}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{apacite}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\APACjournalVolNumPages}[4]{%
  \textbf{\Bem{#1}}%             journal
  \ifx\@empty#2\@empty
  \else
    \unskip, \Bem{#2}%  volume
  \fi
  \ifx\@empty#3\@empty
  \else
    \unskip({#3})%      issue number
  \fi
  \ifx\@empty#4\@empty
  \else
    \unskip, {#4}%      pages
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
blablabla    
\cite{Ham2013}
\cite{Ham2015}
\cite{Wink1991}

\bibliographystyle{myapacite}
\bibliography{mwe}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is this any simpler or better than just redefining `\APACrefatitle` and `\APACrefbtitle`?  That's what they are there for.

Comment: @nickie: They do two different things. Redefining `\APACrefatitle` as your answer demonstrates makes the *title of the journal article* bold. Redefining `\APACjournalVolNumPages` make the *name of the journal bold*.

Comment: Oh, by journal title did she mean the name of the journal?  I.e. "Journal of Personality and Social Psychology".  That was not clear in the question.  You may be right, I'm not sure what she was asking for.

Comment: @nickie: That was my understanding. An example of the expected formatting in the question would have been helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: I am not sure whether I have understood what you are asking.  Is it the **title of the journal paper** that you want to have in bold and italics, or the **name of the journal** itself?  By first reading your question, I assumed the former, so the first part of my answer tackles that.  If it's the latter that you're after, read the second part of my answer for an easier fix than what Guho suggests in his answer.

---

**Typesetting the title in bold and italics**

Quoting from [the documentation of package `apacite`](http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/biblio/bibtex/contrib/apacite/apacite.pdf), on p.42 --- A coincidence? I don't think so... :-)

> The following commands are currently implemented to format the
>   reference list. If you want to customize them, you can study the
>   source code in the file apacite.sty, copy it to you own package file,
>   and adapt the code as desired.

(snip)

> ```
> \APACrefatitle   Title (article style, default upright)
> \APACrefbtitle   Title (book style, default italicized)
> ```

Therefore, if I understand correctly what you want to do, it suffices to add the following line in your code, after `\usepackage{apacite}`.

```
\renewcommand\APACrefatitle[2]{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}
```

Perhaps the advice to copy the source code of the package file was misleading; you  probably do not want to do this for typesetting a single paper, but you'd consider it if this happens regularly. You don't need to touch the bibliography style (`.bst`), as the package provides easy customization for what you want to do.

Notice, however, that this changes only the style of the title of *articles*, therefore the first, unpublished reference to Ham *et al.* will not change.

[image: result 1]

If you want to also change that, you'll have to redefine the other macro too:

```
\renewcommand\APACrefbtitle[2]{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}
```

[image: result 2]

---

**Typesetting the journal name in bold and italics**

After `\usepackage{apacite}` you can add the following three lines:

```
\let\oldAPACjournalVolNumPages\APACjournalVolNumPages
\renewcommand{\APACjournalVolNumPages}[4]{%
  \oldAPACjournalVolNumPages{\textbf{#1}}{#2}{#3}{#4}}
```

This uses the existing definition of `\APACjournalVolNumPages`, instead of defining it anew, and just makes sure that the journal's name is bold (the existing definition will make sure to also use italics).

[image: result 3]

Comment: Oh, well, sorry, I'm fixing it...

Comment: +1 for a better way to redefine `\APAjournalVolNumPages`!