# Modifying book, online and misc title in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, apacite

I want to modify book, online and misc title. They are italic but it must be non-italic. I think, `\APACrefbtitle` (i found in `.bbl` file) is about this. 
I tried some alternatives on the `%\patchcmd{\APACrefbtitle}{} %book, online, misc title` line but i could not be successiful.

I think `\patchcmd{\APACjournalVolNumPages}{\Bem}{\uline}{}{}` line is about all of the journal, volume, number and pages. I only used this for deitalicize and underline the journal title. In additon, i want to deitalicize the volume number but i don't know how can i do this. A modify on this line is affect the journal, volume, number and page.

Thank you.

[image]

**main.tex**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=turkish,english,shorthands=:!]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=30mm,top=30mm,right=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}


\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}





% BIBLIOGRAPHY
\AtBeginDocument{\urlstyle{APACsame}} % Same fonts for URL
%%% Bibliography line spacing
\usepackage{natbib}
\setlength{\bibsep}{0.0pt}
%%% Removing parentheses around year in bibliography
\AtBeginDocument{
\renewcommand{\BBOP}{}
\renewcommand{\BBCP}{}
\renewcommand{\BCBL}{}
\renewcommand{\BCBL}{}

\renewcommand{\BBAA}{ve}
%\renewcommand{\BBAB}{} %What is?
%\renewcommand{\BAnd}{} %What is?
\renewcommand{\BOthers}{vd}
}



\patchcmd{\APACjournalVolNumPages}{\Bem}{\uline}{}{}
%\patchcmd{\APACrefbtitle}{} %book, online, misc title  

%%% Adding ":" character before page number in citations
\bibpunct[: ]{(}{)}{:}{a}{,}{~}
%........................................






\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref} %son yükle



% BEGIN
\begin{document}

% CHAPTER 1
\chapter{GİRİŞ}
\citep{ferretti2001}, \citep{onlinedeneme}, \citet{frattini2013}, \citet{onlinedeneme}'e göre.
\lipsum[1-1]


% CHAPTER 2
% BIBLIOGRAPHY (Kaynaklar)
\renewcommand*\bibname{KAYNAKLAR}
\nocite{*} % Add all references within the .bib file
\phantomsection
\bibliographystyle{apacite}


\setlength{\bibsep}{1\itemsep}
\bibliography{literature}
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

**literature.bib**

```
@article{ferretti2001,
  title     = {Permanent Scatterers in SAR Interferometry},
  author    = {Alessandro Ferretti and Claudio Prati and Fabio Rocca},
  journal   = {IEEE Transactions on Geoscience and Remote Sensing},
  number    = {1},
  volume    = {39},
  pages     = {8--20},
  year      = {2001},
  publisher = {IEEE-INST Electrical Electronics Engineers Inc},
  doi       = {10.1109/36.898661},
}
@article{frattini2013,
  title     = {Damage to Buildings in Large Slope Rock Instabilities
Monitored with the PSInSAR™ Technique},
  author    = {Paolo Frattini and Giovanni B. Crosta and Jacopo Allievi},
  journal   = {Remote Sensing},
  volume    = {5},
  pages     = {4753--4773},
  year      = {2013},
  publisher = {MDPI AG},
  doi       = {10.3390/rs5104753}, 
}
@online{onlinedeneme,
  title     = {Deneme Başlığı},
  author    = {Yazar Zadı and Iyazar Isoyad},
  year      = {2009},
  url       = {http://www.nytimes.com/},
  urldate   = {28 Ocak 2018}
}
@book{pye2010trashculture,
  author    = {John Doe},
  publisher = {Book Company},
  series    = {Cultural Interactions},
  title     = {Cultures of Amazons},
  year      = {2015},
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem comes from a side effect between the `normalem` option of `ulem` package and the `patchcmd`.
The command `\APACjournalVolNumPages` containt to calls to `\Bem` :

```
\meaning\APACjournalVolNumPages
```

prints:

```
\long macro:#1#2#3#4->\Bem {#1}\ifx \@empty #2\@empty \else \unskip , \Bem
{#2}\fi \ifx \@empty #3\@empty \else \unskip ({#3})\fi \ifx \@empty #4\@empty\else \unskip , {#4}\fi
```

with `\Bem -> \protect\emph`

Hence:

- with `\usepackage{ulem}` all the `\emph` are silently  replaced by
  `\uline`. Then, even WITHOUT the `\patchcmd` you get:
  [image]
- With `\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}`, followed by:

`\patchcmd{\APACjournalVolNumPages}{\Bem}{\uline}{\typeout{patch success}}{\typeout{patch failed}}`

only the *first* `\Bem` is replaced by `\uline` (i don't know why) and you get the unwanted result:
[image]

The solution is as follows:

- either do not use the `normalem` option, but all the `\emph` will become underlined.
- or keep the `normalem` but repeat the `\patchmd` to replace also    the second `\Bem`. In this cas you would also have to patch the `\APACrefbtitle` and possibly others.

Your MWEB (minimal working example with bibliography) would then look like:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{literat.bib}
@article{ferretti2001,
  title     = {Permanent Scatterers in {SAR} Interferometry},
  author    = {Alessandro Ferretti and Claudio Prati and Fabio Rocca},
  journal   = {IEEE Transactions on Geoscience and Remote Sensing},
  number    = {1},
  volume    = {39},
  pages     = {8--20},
  year      = {2001},
  publisher = {IEEE-INST Electrical Electronics Engineers Inc},
  doi       = {10.1109/36.898661},
}
@book{pye2010trashculture,
  author    = {Doe, John},
  publisher = {Book Company},
  series    = {Cultural Interactions},
  title     = {Cultures of {A}mazons},
  year      = {2015},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=turkish,english,shorthands=:!]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=30mm,top=30mm,right=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% BIBLIOGRAPHY
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{natbib}

\AtBeginDocument{
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\patchcmd{\APACjournalVolNumPages}{\Bem}{\uline}{\typeout{**patch success**}}{\typeout{**patch failed**}}
\patchcmd{\APACjournalVolNumPages}{\Bem}{\textnormal}{\typeout{**patch2 success**}}{\typeout{**patch2 failed**}}
\patchcmd{\APACrefbtitle}{\Bem}{\textnormal}{\typeout{**patch3 success**}}{\typeout{**patch3 failed**}}
\renewcommand{\BBAA}{ve}
\renewcommand{\BOthers}{vd}
% Removing parentheses around year in bibliography
\renewcommand{\BBOP}{}
\renewcommand{\BBCP}{}
\renewcommand{\BCBL}{}
\renewcommand{\BCBL}{}
\urlstyle{APACsame}
% Adding ":" character before page number in citations
\bibpunct[: ]{(}{)}{:}{a}{,}{~}
% Bibliography line spacing
\setlength{\bibsep}{1\itemsep}
}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref} %son yükle

\begin{document}
\chapter{GİRİŞ}
\citep{ferretti2001}, \citep{pye2010trashculture}
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
\renewcommand*\bibname{KAYNAKLAR}
\bibliography{literat}
\end{document}
```

By the way, *underlining* is an ugly bad habit inherited from typewriter's age, and if it's not mandatory, avoid it !

Comment: Off-topic : in ``bib`` files the pure numbers like for ``year`` or ``volume`` are normally written without braces, e.g. ``year=2001,``

Comment: I read a title https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286297/change-bst-file-to-get-journal-name-bold/287729#287729 Is the problem have an another answer here? The codes at this level are far above my knowledge (:

Comment: This reference deals on modifying the ``.bst`` file. This is actually much lore involved, and should be avoided as long as possible. The ``apacite`` package (``.sty``) and style (``.bst``) that you use make such stuff unnecessary, as the formatting in the ``bbl`` is not hard coded but deferred to LaTeX thanks to the commands ``\APACjournalVolNumPages`` ,``BC**`` and  siblings.  

It is hence enough to be able to slightly modify them with ``\patchcmd``, or if needed to ``\renewcommand`` them in a similar way as the latex code provided by Guho in the accepted answer of this reference.